# Social Links Menu displays icon instead of text (twentyfifteen)

Tags: menus

**EDIT:** I posted too hastily. I just discovered that the solution to my problem is to bypass the regular Menus section and create a custom WIDGET, which can serve as a custom menus box. Below is my original post. I'll delete this post if you like.

---

I'm working with the theme twentyfifteen, which allows you to create two menus that are displayed in the sidebar.

I had no trouble creating the first menu, which is simply a list of links to the top pages on my site.

The second menu apparently has to be a "Social Links Menu" by default. For each new link you create, you're allowed to enter a URL and Navigation Label. For the Navigation Label, I entered the text that I assumed would display.

But when I preview my page, I don't see any text. Instead, I see a horizontal row of small, circular icons. Clicking on an icon takes me to the page I linked to, but visitors won't have a clue what they're clicking, since the icons all look the same.

Can anyone tell me how to convert the icons to conventional links?

Comment: Yikes, I think I just stumbled across the answer - the Social Links Menu is reserved for SOCIAL sites, like Facebook. https://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/social-links-menu/ So should I delete my question and post a new one? I would like to know how to add a second menu that lists links to other websites.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE WordBear :) No need to delete your question, you can [edit it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/227631/edit) to modify what you want to ask. However the site you linked to there is for wordpress.com sites - we're only able to help with self-hosted sites here (commonly known as wordpress.org) sites. Is yours self-hosted?

Comment: Yes, my site is self-hosted. I wasn't aware that I linked to wordpress.com.

Comment: No problem. I'm unfamiliar with twentyfifteen so I'll let someone else answer this, but https://codex.wordpress.org/Twenty_Fifteen might answer some questions you have in general. Otherwise, I definitely recommend editing your post to clarify, and also state where you want to add the second menu. For example, you can add a custom menu in a widget area (sidebar) which might suit what you need.

Comment: Bingo - you answered my question: WIDGET. Thx.

Comment: No probs. Noticed your edit - no need to delete your post, it can help others who come across it with the same query. You are allowed to answer your own post (and then accept your own answer after 48 hours). Would you like to do that? Probably worth you checking out the [site tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and also the page [Can I answer my own question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Yes, I'll take the Site Tour and answer my question.